# Flutter Deserialization Lists of Lists

Tags: json, list, flutter, serialization, deserialization

I have a problem with my project to deSerialize Lists of Lists for which I can't find a solution. I have three classes: records which have reference and a value, experiments which have a name and list of records, and projects which have a name and list of of experiments. My code looks like below. I have the correct fromJson for records and experiments, but can't get the right fromJson for project. Can you help ? Also is my toJson for projects correct ?
Many thanks, appreciate your help.

```
class Project {
  final String name;
  final List<Experiment> experiments;
  Project({this.name, this.experiments});

  factory Project.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'experiments': experiments,
      };
}

class Experiment {
  String name;
  List<Record> records;
  Experiment({this.name, this.records});

   factory Experiment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['records'] as List;
    List<Record> imagesList = list.map((i) => Record.fromJson(i)).toList();
   return Experiment(records: imagesList, name: json['name']);
  }

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'records': records,
      };
}

class Record {
  final double time;
  final double value;
  Record({this.time, this.value});

  factory Record.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Record(time: json['time'], value: json['value']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'time': time,
        'value': value,
      };
}`
```

Comment: Following seems to work actually :factory Project.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['experiments'] as List;
    print(list);
    List<Experiment> imagesList = list.map((i) => Experiment.fromJson(i)).toList();
    print('------');
    print(imagesList[2].records[1].value);
    return Project(name: json['name'], experiments: imagesList);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use this library https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper
Instead of manually hard coding 'from/to'JSON methods.

It will allow you to nicely map your complicated JSON to Dart Classes
and make your model code neat and dead simple.